# Calling AWS Lambda function from another Lambda function using node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to call AWS Lambda function from another AWS Lambda function, but lambda function is not being called from another lambda function.

Please find 2 lambda functions below. First Lambda function is calling Another-lambda function but another lambda function is not getting called and not logging the console.log in another-lambda function.

console.log in first lambda function inside promise before lambda.invoke is getting logged but the callback function inside lambda.invoke is not logging any statement.

First Lambda function

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({ region: 'us-east-1' });

const callAnotherLambdaFunc = async () => {
  return await new Promise((res, rej) => {
    var params = {
      FunctionName: 'Another-Lambda',
      InvocationType: "RequestResponse",
      Payload: '{ "name" : "Alex" }',
      LogType: "Tail",
    };
    
    console.log("Promise") // This is getting logged
  
    try {
      lambda.invoke(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error ", err).  // This is not getting logged
          context.fail(err);
        } else {
          console.log("TKK Success ", data.payload)   // This is not getting logged
          context.succeed('Another Lambda said '+ data.Payload);
        }
      }); 
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Exception", e)   // This is not getting logged
    }
  })
}

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Auto-Trading!'),
    };
    
    console.log(event.queryStringParameters.testKey12, " context ", context)    // This is getting logged
    
    callAnotherLambdaFunc();
    
    return response;  // Postman can see Hello from Auto-Trading! from response object.
};
```

Another-lambda

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Another Lambda!'),
    };
    
    console.log("Another Lambda Event ", event, " Context ", context)  // This is not being logged.
    
    return response;
};
```

Please let me know what am I missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the first Lambda function have Internet connectivity? (Either by _not_ being connected to a VPC, or by using a NAT Gateway?)

Comment: Just tested First lambda with https://github.com/mihaerzen/lambda-internet-access-checker/blob/master/index.js and I am getting the content. So, yes first lambda has internet access.

Answer (score 1):

Since the callAnotherLambdaFunc function is asynchronous and returns a promise, you should use await when calling it. ex

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Auto-Trading!'),
    };
    
    console.log(event.queryStringParameters.testKey12, " context ", context)    // This is getting logged
    
    await callAnotherLambdaFunc();
    
    return response;  // Postman can see Hello from Auto-Trading! from response object.
};
```

Also, another way to call the lambda functions that you can use and that I have used is:

```
var params = {
      FunctionName: 'Another-Lambda',
      InvocationType: "RequestResponse",
      Payload: '{ "name" : "Alex" }',
      LogType: "Tail",
    };
console.log("Promise") // This is getting logged
try {
  return await lambda.invoke(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error ", err).  // This is not getting logged
      } else {
        console.log("TKK Success ", data.payload)   // This is not getting logged
      }
  }).promise(); 
} catch (e) {
   console.log("Exception", e)   // This is not getting logged
}
```